# php Get data from 1 table depending on data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the apartment owner's details (name and email) stored in the 'clients' table, depending on which apartment is selected, details of which are stored in the 'appmt_user' table.
I have the following public function which I can't get to work.

```
public function getOwnerdetails($appmt_id){
    $ownerid = mysql_query("select user_id from  appmt_user where appmt_id=".$appmt_id);

    $ownerdetails = mysql_query("select first_name , surname , email from  clients  where client_id=".$ownerid);
    return $ownerdetails;
}
```

The variable $ownerid seams to be empty when I do a print_r, so no data is returned in $ownerdetails.
Do I need to save $ownerid somewhere first?

Comment: You have to call `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get a row of results from a query. I can't believe this comes up every single day, don't you know how to follow tutorials?

Comment: Also, you should use a JOIN to combine the two queries.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, combine the two queries with a `JOIN`. Second, you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get a row of results from a query -- `mysql_query()` just returns a resource, not the values you selected.

```
public function getOwnerdetails($appmt_id) {
    $appmt_id = intval($appmt_id); // Sanitize input
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT c.first_name, c.surname, c.email
                            FROM clients AS c
                            JOIN appmt_user AS a ON c.clients_id = a.user_id
                            WHERE a.appmt_id = $appmt_id");
    $ownerdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    return $ownerdetails;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise I had to use mysql-fetch_assoc. I have another function which works fine without it and returns 12 valuses no problem.  public function getApartmentdetails($id){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from  apartment_master  where status=true and appmt_id=".$id));
  return $row;
 }

Comment: That function is calling `mysql_fetch_assoc`, it's right after `$row =`.

Comment: So it does! - DOH!! How did I miss that? - Thanks for your help it all works fine now.